# On ubuntu 20.4, after starting Cassandra with systemctl, no process listens at port 7000/9042/7199

Tags: ubuntu, systemctl, port

I installed a 3-nodes Cassandra cluster on three machines (all running Ubuntu 20.4) .

I could start either via systemctl start cassandra, or via cassandra -f command.

But I noticed that if I start via systemctl start cassandra, even though systemctl status cassandra shows the service is active and running:

```
root@:~# systemctl status cassandra

root@csidclppa0056:~# systemctl status cassandra

cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-08-22 01:05:08 PDT; 2s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1423026 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 154174)
     Memory: 5.1G
     CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service
             └─1423129 java -ea -da:net.openhft... -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -X>
```

However, there is no any process listening at ports 7000, 9042 or 7199.

Hence nodetool status fails, with this error message:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

cqlsh would also fail as no process is listening at port 9042.

On the contrary, if I start via cassandra -f command, all three ports are being listened at by related Cassandra processes. And therefore commands nodetool status and cqlsh all work as expected.

Did I miss anything here? Why systemctl start cassandra doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Post the full command you're starting cassandra with, also the contents of your config file and the last few lines of your system.log when starting cassandra with systemd

Comment: Also look at (but don't post) `sudo lsof -ccassandra;sudo lsof -i`. Any ports open by `cassandra`? If not, your configuration is wrong.

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of trying to start `cassandra`.